# How to add countdown-timer to UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I'm quite new to Swift and couldn't find any good explanation for this. I want the user to select a duration (h:m:s) when clicking on a UITextField in an alert and display the value in the textField.
Can someone please give me a hint or an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITextField has delegate protocol called UITextFieldDelegate

in your viewController:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    yourTextField.delegate = self
}
```

Conform your viewController to this delegate. There is a textFieldShouldBeginEditing method, it is called when the user taps into the textfield. You return false here, so the textField won't became first responder and the keyboard will not open and you can present your picker.

```
extension viewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        //open your alert here
        openPicker()

        return false
    }

}
```

You can use UIPickerView to present to the user. You can read about that here and even create it based on the example:
[explanation and example of UIPickerView](https://codewithchris.com/uipickerview-example/)